# call a class level method in scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

I make a class level method for Alert:

```
@interface TestAlert
@end
+ (void)showErrorAlert:(NSTimer *)message
{
.......
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:messageIn delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

and I want to call it directly in `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` like:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:TestAlert selector:@selector( showErrorAlert:) userInfo:error repeats:NO];
```

There have grammar error of course.

I know I can put `showErrorAlert` to a method:

```
- (void)showError:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    //NSLog(@"show error %@", error);
    [TestAlert showErrorAlert:(NSString *)[timer userInfo]];
}
```

Then

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(showError:) userInfo:error1 repeats:NO];
```

But it will cause crash when `showErrorAlert` is called, because error message from `showErro`r method has been released.

Can i call `showErrorAlert` directly, If I can't, how should I avoid error message's release ?

Comment: how about using `perform selector` method?

Comment: @Bazinga Perform selector should be the last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `[TestAlert class]` as a target instead of `TestAlert`.

Comment: I can't, because I haven't 15 reputation. But I will go back to this page, and accept it when i get 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this.
You can find all the types of provided performSelector: methods here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

- performSelector:
- performSelector:withObject:
- performSelector:withObject:withObject: 
  – performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
- performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:
- performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
- performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
- performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
- performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
- performSelectorInBackground:withObject: