# NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval and target is "class level function"

Tags: swift

How to set *target* in Swift (to call a class level function) the way it is done in obj-c:

[call a class level method in scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044305/call-a-class-level-method-in-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval)

Comment: EDIT: I could not find anywhere the answer to my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class MyClass: NSObject{

  class func startTimer(){
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: MyClass.self, selector: "callByTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

  }

  class func callByTimer(timer: NSTimer!){
    println("Called")
  }

}

MyClass.startTimer()
```